# TypeError: undefined is not a function (for JQuery Sortables)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am creating an HTML UI where there are "rooms" and you can place devices in these rooms. I use JQuery Sortable widget. *I use this code to setup my sortables:*

```
function setupSortables() {
        $(".sortableHorizontal")
        .sortable({
            connectWith: ".sortableHorizontal",
            cancel: ".unsortable",
            revert: animationSpeed,
            "placeholder": 'sortPlaceholder',  
            "opacity": 0.5,
                "start": function (event, ui) {
                    var $item = ui.item;
                    $(".sortPlaceholder").css({
                        "margin-top": $(".deviceContainer").css("margin-top"),
                        "margin-left": $(".deviceContainer").css("margin-left"),
                        "height": $(".deviceContainer").height() - ($(".sortPlaceholder").css("border-width").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '') * 2) + "px",
                    });
                },  
                "stop": function(event, ui) {
                        //alert(ui.item.parent().attr("id"));
                    updateRoomDimensions();
                    relocateSmarthomeObject(ui.item);
                }
        })
        .disableSelection()
        .css({
            "min-height": $(".deviceContainer").outerHeight(true),
            "min-width": $(".deviceContainer").outerWidth(true),
            "padding-right": "15px"
        });
    }
```

I call this method on `$(document).ready()` since I already have preexisting rooms. *But when I create a new room using this code:*

```
function createRoom() {
        var roomName = $("#roomCreator").find("#name").val();
        var roomColor = $("#roomCreator").find("#color").text();
        $.get("/devices/createRoom", {
            "name": roomName,
            "color": roomColor
        }, function(data, status) {
            $("#notif").html(data);
            $("#responses").html(data);

            var ssid = $("#responses").find("#SSID").val();
            if(ssid != null) {
                var html = "\
                    <li id='" + ssid + "' class='root_sortItem'> \
                        <div class='invisible'> \
                            <div class='invisible roomContainerContainer'> \
                                <div id='r_" + ssid + "' class='roomContainer' style='background-color:" + roomColor + ";'> \
                                    <div id='r_" + ssid + "_nameContainer' class='textBigBold roomHeader'> \
                                        <span id='r_" + ssid + "_name'>" + roomName + "</span> \
                                        <div class='overlay'> \
                                            <img class='move'/> \
                                            <img class='edit'/> \
                                        </div> \
                                    </div> \
                                    <ul id='" + ssid + "' class='sortableHorizontal room_sort' style='width:165px; height:198px; border:solid 1px blue;'> \
                                    </ul> \
                                </div> \
                            </div> \
                        </div> \
                    </li> ";
                var $html = $(html);
                $("#root_sort").append($html);
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    setupSortables();
                });
            }
        });
        closeRoomCreator();
    }
```

And call the first *setupSortables()* method, it returns:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...$(".sortableHorizontal")
        .sortable...')
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Are you loading your script correctly? I mean all the dependencies in the correct order. Try writing $. in console and and then check for the methods available

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Some of the syntax does not look correct. I would advise using jshint.com to confirm your code syntax and remove any potential errors. Do you see any other preceding errors in console that might indicate jQuery  and UI libraries are not loading?

Comment: It also appears you have `ssid` used as 2 of the `id` attributes. First for the `li` and second for a later `ul` element. `id` attributes must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise updating to using jQuery objects instead of HTML strings.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pto4bke0/3/

**JavaScript**

```
var animationSpeed = "fast";

function setupSortables() {
  $(".sortableHorizontal")
    .sortable({
      connectWith: ".sortableHorizontal",
      cancel: ".unsortable",
      revert: animationSpeed,
      placeholder: 'sortPlaceholder',
      opacity: 0.5,
      start: function(event, ui) {
        var $item = ui.item;
        $(".sortPlaceholder").css({
          "margin-top": $(".deviceContainer").css("margin-top"),
          "margin-left": $(".deviceContainer").css("margin-left"),
          "height": $(".deviceContainer").height() - ($(".sortPlaceholder").css("border-width").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '') * 2) + "px",
        });
      },
      "stop": function(event, ui) {
        //alert(ui.item.parent().attr("id"));
        //updateRoomDimensions();
        //relocateSmarthomeObject(ui.item);
      }
    })
    .disableSelection()
    .css({
      "min-height": $(".deviceContainer").outerHeight(true),
      "min-width": $(".deviceContainer").outerWidth(true),
      "padding-right": "15px"
    });
}

function createRoom() {
  var roomName = $("#roomCreator").find("#name").val();
  var roomColor = $("#roomCreator").find("#color").val();

  var ssid = 1000 + $(".root_sortItem").length;
  if (ssid != null) {
    var $li = $("<li>", {
      id: ssid,
      class: "root_sortItem"
    });
    $("<div>", {
      class: "invisible"
    }).appendTo($li);
    $("<div>", {
      class: "invisible roomContainerContainer"
    }).appendTo($li.find(".invisible"));
    $("<div>", {
      id: "r_" + ssid,
      class: "roomContainer",
      style: "background-color: " + roomColor + ";"
    }).appendTo($li.find(".roomContainerContainer"));
    $("<div>", {
      id: "r_" + ssid + "_nameContainer",
      class: "textBigGold roomHeader"
    }).appendTo($li.find(".roomContainer"));
    $("<span>", {
      id: "r_" + ssid + "_name"
    }).html(roomName).appendTo($li.find(".roomHeader"));
    $("<div>", {
      class: "overlay"
    }).appendTo($li.find(".roomHeader"));
    $("<img>", {
      class: "move"
    }).appendTo($li.find(".overlay"));
    $("<img>", {
      class: "edit"
    }).appendTo($li.find(".overlay"));
    $("<ul>", {
      id: "rs_" + ssid,
      class: "sortableHorizontal room_sort",
      style: "width:165px; height:198px; border:solid 1px blue;"
    }).appendTo($li.find(".roomContainer"));
    $("#root .sortableHorizontal").eq(0).append($li);
  }
}

$(function() {
  setupSortables();
  $("#createRoomBtn").click(createRoom);
});
```

I had to take some guesses as you did not provide a very complete example.